# How do I input custom variables in User::create() in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, variables, hash, passwords

```
$user = User::create(request(['name', 'email', 'password']));
```

In the above code, what syntax do I need to use to replace the request()->password variable with a custom $password variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest approach would be:

```
$vars = request(['name','email']);
$vars['password'] = $password;
$user = User::create($vars);
```

Comment: @SimonSuh this is the correct way to replace password, as in boilerplate model the password always [`hidden`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/User.php#L26). **edit** also `guarded` can't be filled en masse - can read more on [the docs regarding eloquent models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent).